# Getting a GridBagLayout's cells' pixel dimensions

Tags: java, awt, gridbaglayout

Is it possible to find the current dimensions in pixels of a requested cell (x,y) in a GridBagLayout JPanel?

**EDIT:** My usage would be to have a JLabel that fills the area provided by the layout.  I want to give it the maximum size made available to it.

Comment: Not that I know of. The question is why do you think you need this information. If we know the requirement we may be able so suggest a better/different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My usage would be to have a JLabel that fills the area provided by the layout. I want to give it the maximum size made available to it.

That is the job of the layout manager. You are not supposed to specify the size of a component.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use a GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). You will want to specify the "fill" constraint when you add the component to the layout.

Maybe other layout managers can solve your problem as well. The tutorial has examples for all the layout mangers.

Comment: Removing setPreferred/MaximumSize calls did exactly what I wanted.